# How to insert into a table from a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that selects 11 players out of 20 (based on their positions) for each match. What I’ve done is created a new table know as ‘FixturePlayer’ to simply store in a PlayerID and FixtureID into the table.

I am not sure however on how I can insert pl.PlayerID and pl.FixtureID into 'PlayerFixture' table as I am already calling a select. What should I do?

```
WITH pl AS (SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID
                           ,p.Position
                           ,CASE WHEN p.TeamID = 0 THEN 0
                                 ELSE p.playerWeighting END AS playerWeighting
                           ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
                           ,t.TeamID
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1)
,po AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk FROM pl)
,total AS (SELECT TeamID
             ,SUM(playerWeighting) AS TeamWeight
             ,SUM((playerWeighting / 10) * Form + playerWeighting) AS FinalTeamWeight
       FROM po
       WHERE (po.Position = 'GK' and po.rnk  = 1) OR 
             (po.Position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
             (po.Position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
             (po.Position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
       GROUP BY po.TeamID
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MatchDay_Insert]

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

    SELECT [TeamID], [TeamWeight], [Form], [FinalTeamWeight]
    FROM TeamWeighting
    ORDER BY TeamID


    select * from player
END
```

PlayerFixture:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PlayerFixture]
(
    [FixtureID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [PlayerID] INT NULL 
)
```

Comment: Provide the DDL of the PlayerFixture table, and what data should be inserted based on the sample data above.

Comment: I have rephrased the question and included the schemas for PlayerFixture table

Answer (score 0):

The question is slightly unclear but I think you are actually wondering how to use the same `cte` twice?  Once for inserting data into `dbo.PlayerFixture` and once for Selecting your data?

The way I always do this is a temp table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TblName') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TblName
    END

;WITH cte AS (
....cte definition
)

INSERT INTO #TblName (Col1,....)
SELECT
   Col1
FROM
   cte

INSERT INTO dbo.PlayerFixture (FixtureId, PlayerId)
SELECT
    FixtureId
    ,PlayerId
FROM
   #TblName

SELECT *
FROM
   #TblName
```

And if you where just meaning how do you get the data from teh 3 cte's you have defined above simply write the `INSERT INTO dbo.PlayerFixture SELECT` directly after your cte definition though that doesn't look like what you want from the cte's themselves.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Virtually what I meant was that the code I have got picks 11 players, I want to insert those players 'PlayerID' and 'FixtureID' into table 'PlayerFixture' table. Only issue is that I already have a SELECT statement so not sure how to get around this problem

Comment: Also with the code you suggested, do I place this in the proc or view?

Comment: it won't work in a view because you are creating a temp table.  You could switch the temp table to a table variable and do it in a table valued function which essentially is like a view.  Or you could do it in a stored proc.  But if you want to use the cte results twice you will have to create some form of temporarily holding your cte results then doing your operations on that temporary table

Comment: Cool, tried i but not got it to work because reference error with pl, (my cte reference). If you don't mind can you post the full code so I can see what it should be. Don't know If I need to include a CTE within the proc and if so then what to define it to.

Comment: please edit your question with what you tried that way I can just work off what you have.  Also because your code above doesn't have all of the pieces (e.g. SELECT) you were discussing.